How can I configure a WIFI-connected printer in a VM on a NAT connection?
I am running a Windows 10 VM in Qemu, using Virt-Manager. The network connection of the VM is NAT.
The host is MX Linux (based on Debian Bookworm).
I have a Brother MFC-L2710DW printer that is connected to my home network by WIFI.
If I try to set up the printer in the VM, it doesn't matter whether I use the downloaded Brother software or the default Windows drivers, the result is the same:
Windows is unable to automatically detect the printer. So I manually enter into the printer wizard the IP that the printer shows me, which is in the XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX format.
Then the printer is "successfully" added, and set to default. But when I print a test page, it fails.
The printing queue says "Spooling" and then "Printer Busy or Error", and the printer settings say "Printer status: Default, error"
I tried disabling firewall in both host and guest, but it didn't help.
I actually tried doing this on a bridged connection, but the result was the same, so I switched back to NAT...

Is the printer's IP able to be pinged from the VM? This sounds like a router firewall and/or networking issue - what's the IP subnet of the VM and printer?

To answer my own question, the IP address to be used in the Windows printer wizard should be in the format of XX.X.X.X
In other words, you need to omit all the extra zeros that the printer adds to the IP address.
